# Why "Rails -v" and "Bundle exec rails -v" is different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, bundler

I have staging and productions servers through AWS. After a certain point of time(I think it was after I upgraded ruby version to 2.1), my staging/production servers couldn't find rails so I had to ssh in and redownload Rails and Ruby, but now when I run "rails -v" it gives me 2.3.14, but when I run "bundle exec rails -v" I get the proper 3.2.16.

I'm guessing this is because of paths, but not entirely sure how to solve this. Some of the answers I found suggested changing the .bashrc and changing the $PATH variable, but wasn't exactly sure what to change it to.

This is my .bashrc:

```
 #PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # how it was before 
 PATH = $PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin #edited this just now to see if it works. it didnt..
```

Comment: Your current gemset and your `Gemfile` appear to have different versions of rails installed. have you tried `gem install rails --version 3.2.16`? Kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle exec rails` will use the rails version defined in your `Gemfile`. On the other hand, a simple `rails` will run the latest version available on your computer.

What probably happened is this:

you had a rails version from rvm that was the same as the one used in your `Gemfile` (3.2.16), so you were not noticing any difference. After upgrading ruby, you have to reinstall all gems you did install on your previous version. Otherwise it will fallback to the latest available, *which can be the system version* (ie. not from rvm). This may explain why you have such an outdated one.

Note that a proper `bundle install` will install all the gems required in your `Gemfile` and then will do the job for you.

Comment: Except that the version not in the `Gemfile` is showing up as older - I think it will use whatever is installed in your current gemset.

Comment: yes or the system one, or may come from a manual installation, or a different gemset (not really sure how rvm handles that kind of thing, I much prefer rbenv). Anyway, hard to tell without more informations